# Can you prevent a VisualForce component from rendering until it's contents become visible?

Tags: ajax, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a VisualForce page that contains two components which are each inside of a tab, like this:

```
<apex:tabpanel switchtype="ajax" selectedTab="tab1">
    <apex:tab label="First Tab" name="tab1" id="tab1">
     <c:firstComponent /> 
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Second Tab" name="tab2" id="tab2">
    <c:secondComponent />
    </apex:tab>
</apex:tabpanel>
```

Is it possible to prevent the page from running the code in secondComponent (contained in tab2) until the user actually clicks on the second tab?

This is a specific case, of the more general question: is it possible to NOT run all of the code on a page when it first loads and only run it when the user takes a particular action.

(One reason for wanting to do this is to reduce the number of queries on the page to avoid hitting the limit.)

Comment: Sounds like you're after lazy loading (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload but I think it's only for images). Some kind of onload/onfocus/onclick event? apex:actionSupport tag? Also - read up about `rendered` attribute (present on most tags; imagine a search form and displaying pageBlockTable only when `rendered={!results.size>0}`) and `rerender` (useful when commandbutton or commandlink was used and the page was submitted, need to refresh only part of the page)

Comment: Good thinking, but unfortunately, when I look at the logs it looks to me like the code still executes when you use rendered="false", it just does not display the output.

Answer (score 1):

I think it works as you want! You probably have too much logic in the constructors. And [component's constructor HAS TO execute](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_controller_get_request.htm).

Check this example, it works for me (meaning exception is thrown only when I navigate to the second tab).

```
public class tabTest{
    public Contact getContact(){
        throw new exampleException('That\'s no moon. It\'s a space station.');
    }
    public class exampleException extends Exception{}
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="tabTest">
    <apex:tabpanel switchtype="ajax" selectedTab="tab1">
        <apex:tab name="tab1" label="1st" >1</apex:tab>
        <apex:tab name="tab2" label="it's a trap!">{!contact.LastName}</apex:tab>
    </apex:tabpanel>
</apex:page>
```

Do you have a lot of logic invoked when constructors are invoked (on the main page and then for each of the components)? Can you move some of it into action methods (the ones returning getter methods:

```
public List<Contact> myData{
    get{
        if(myData == null){
            myData = [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 5];
        }
        return myData;
    }
    private set;
}
```

I know it looks crazy but it's a [valid syntax since 2008](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2008/06/property-access.html) ;) You can also have a traditional `getMyData()` call.

It's a matter of preference but I try to make my constructors as thin as possible, only basic initialisation. If I'll start fetching all kinds of stuff it means delay for the end user who might not need all the data every time.

As for the more generic question about running code when user performs an action - there's whole range of tags & options: commandButtons, commandLinks, actionSupport, actionFunction, JavaScript remoting... I'm not going to paste all the links but there are tons of examples, not the least of them being http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Visualforce_DynamicEditPage.

Comment: You identified the problem exactly; code is running because it is in the constructor. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, that was not the problem after all. The problem is that variables in <apex:repeat> tags are always evaluated, in every tab, when the page first loads. Here is an example, slightly modified from what you provided:

Comment: `public class tabTest{
 
  public List<Contact> myData{
     get{
         if(myData == null){
             myData = [SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact LIMIT 5];
              throw new exampleException('That\'s no asteroid. It\'s a space station.');
         }
         return myData;
     }
     private set;
 }   
  
 
    public class exampleException extends Exception{}
    

}`

Comment: `<apex:page controller="tabTest">
    <apex:tabpanel switchtype="ajax" selectedTab="tab1">
        <apex:tab name="tab1" label="1st" >1</apex:tab>
        <apex:tab name="tab2" label="it's a trap!">
   <apex:repeat var="ct" value="{!MyData}">
    {!ct.LastName}
   </apex:repeat>
        </apex:tab>
    </apex:tabpanel>
</apex:page>`

Comment: The exception is thrown on the first get, even though the `<apex:repeat>` is in the second tab.